# When are the Queueable/Batchable penalties going to be enforced?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, queueable-interface

According to [The New Apex Queueable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html), from October 2014, we were told that chained Queueable calls would be exponentially delayed up to 64 seconds, chaining Batches would be exponentially delayed up to 240 seconds (four minutes), and suicide scheduling would be restricted to 300 seconds (five minute) minimums. This has a considerable impact on some of our code, which would would make Queueable an attractive option over Batchable (except for, of course, I don't know if we can [chain queueables that callout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70149/can-we-callout-and-chain-a-queueable-class)). Today, in Spring '15, nothing behaves the way it's documented there. Are these limitations still coming, or have they been scrapped?

Comment: There is a critical update around Flex Queue that must be activated that I wonder if it controls this. It looks like it has an auto-activation date of May 22. Do you have that activated in your org?

Comment: @DanielHoechst Suicide scheduling is still running at 60 seconds, batches are running steady about 20 executes per minute per batch (it's designed to chain once per minute by estimation), so everything seems to be as it was before. I have noticed "some" slow down with batch processing, but it seems more related to performance fluctuations by system load rather than any intentional throttling (it was doing this before I turned on the Critical Update).

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox what is a normal queue latency in your projects? We are seeing it as high as 10 minutes: http://imgur.com/x1wz3CA

Comment: FYI I've noticed in a production org recently that chaining queueable jobs is slowing down and holding queueable jobs up to a minute before processing - I'm not sure if this is new or not. I'm not seeing the same results in dev orgs because [an AsyncException is still thrown if you try to chain a queueable job more than 5 times](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/system-asyncexception-maximum-callout-depth-has-been-reached) (but production orgs don't have the same limits)

Comment: Queueable chain backoff limits are definitely implemented now and have been since I started working with examples of this in V39 (so it could have been many versions beforehand). My experience that significant backoff occurs after depth3

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the heads up. I'm going to go experiment now...

Comment: Maybe we'll be lucky and they won't bother with this until after they finally get this item from 9 years ago squared away https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brb6AAC

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, 
Are you still facing this error? Can you please provide solutions if you have resolved?

Comment: @VirendraKhatke No error, just wondering when/if the penalties will be enforced. I haven't observed them yet, even to this day.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the penalty delays for chained Queueables in the past (although documentation is rubbish with regards to this). We have 8-10 chained Queueables at times and the `AsyncApexJob` entries would show a ~60s delay between Completion and Creation but we have not seen these delays for a while now (I would say at least since 1 year ago).