# Future Method: Too many future calls : 51

Tags: apex, api, future

Working on a future method to post values to external web service. But since there is a limit of 50 callouts per invocation, I am getting error "Too many future calls : 51". Cases are loaded into salesforce from external ETL in bulk. So is there a way to workaround this error.

**Class**

```
public with sharing class caseTrigger {  
   //method invoked by trigger after insert
    public void CaseInsert(List<Case> caseIns){
          list<Id> caseIds = new list<id>();
            List<Case> caseList = [Select id from case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];
                for(Case c : caseList){
                    if(c.Status != 'closed'){
                        caseIds.add(c.id);
                    }         
                if(f.caseId_User.size()>0){PostCases(caseIds);}
     }
    //postCases (future method)
    @future(callout = true)
    public static void PostCases(List<Id> Ids){
        //prepare Json to post to webservice
   }
}
```

Comment: You should look at the Dan Appleman Asynchronous Apex Pattern which works around this issue -- google it (there's an excellent You Tube video from dreamforce that goes over it)

Comment: found it. Thanks crop1645. Will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a batch job rather than starting the future method directly from the trigger.

I.e.

1. Trigger fires, and starts/queues the batch job to process the new cases that were just inserted. The batch job should support callouts (`Database.AllowsCallouts`).
2. The batch jobs `execute` method is called with the Case details for the newly inserted records.
3. The `execute` method performs the required callout.

If the number of transactions inserting cases becomes significant you might be better of with a non-trigger based sync process. The common approach here is to have a scheduled job start a batch at some interval. The batch job will run using a SOQL query that indicates the Cases that still need to be processed. You would need to determine a mechanism to identify the Cases that still need to be processed. This could be as simple as a checkbox custom field on the Cases that gets flagged once the sync is complete.

Comment: Daniel, Will Queueable interface resolve my issue instead ? I am going through its documentation and trying to find if there can be multiple records passed in one call and if yes, what is the limit..

Comment: @pmvsdt As far as I know, not yet. I asked [a question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70149/can-we-callout-and-chain-a-queueable-class) about this, no response. If you read the behavior, you'll see queuable isn't apparently yet suitable for callout chaining.