# How to mix getContentAsPDF calls with DML?

Tags: asynchronous, queueable-interface, getcontent, critical-update, getcontentaspdf

This critical update:

> PageReference getContent() and getContentAsPDF() Methods Treated as
>   Callouts

will be auto-activated in January 2016.

We have some code that uses a queue of custom event objects where listener classes can be registered that both consume those events (in one case that means making `getContentAsPDF` calls) and can insert additional events. With the critical update turned on that can result in the:

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before
>   calling out.

error because:

- a PDF can be generated (a callout)
- then some events inserted (DML)
- then another PDF can be generated (a callout) that produces the error.

Future calls can't be chained so they are out.

With the encouragement of [Make Calls to PageReference.getContent() in Asynchronous Apex](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_pagereference_getcontent.htm) that mentions `Queueable` a chained `Queueable` looked like the way to go:

```
public static void fire() {
    String requestId = insertEvents();
    if (requestId != null) System.enqueueJob(new FireQueueable(requestId));
}

public class FireQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private String requestId;
    public FireQueueable(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        if (fireFor(requestId)) {
            String nextRequestId = insertEvents();
            if (nextRequestId != null) System.enqueueJob(new FireQueueable(nextRequestId));
        }
    }
}
```

but that generates:

> System.AsyncException: Maximum callout depth has been reached.

as described in [Can we callout and chain a Queueable class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70149/can-we-callout-and-chain-a-queueable-class) and [Allow callouts from chained queueable Apex jobs](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dl7VAAS).

I'm starting to think there is no solution to this problem. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Looks like Queueable is broken in yet more ways than I'd imagined. You're better off with a Batchable process. I found something that should probably do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allowed a single queueable call per database execute method, so this code should technically work:

```
// Must use Database.AllowsCallouts for PDF generation
public with sharing class GenerateOnePDF implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Blob v = Page.myPDFPage.getContentAsPDF();
        // Do your DML here.
    }
}

// Limit one enqueueJob per execute.
public with sharing class GeneratePDFFiles implements Database.Batchable<integer> {
    public Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // Change this logic as you like.
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, integer[] scope) {
        System.enqueueJob(new GenerateOnePDF()); // You'd pass your request ID, I suppose.
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

However, in both my Developer Edition and Sandbox orgs, the Queueable calls *froze*. They were stuck in "processing" for an absurd amount of time, given the following code for `myPDFPage`:

```
<apex:page>
</apex:page>
```

I think you're going to have to open a case with technical support. I wish I had a better answer for you, but I think something's broken.

---

Alternatively, you should be able to just make a Batchable class and do stuff:

```
public with sharing class GeneratePDFS implements Database.Batchable<Integer>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    String priorId;
    Integer counter = 0;
    String insertEvents() {
        insert new Account(Name=counter.format());
            return ++counter > 5? null: counter.format(); 
    }

    public Integer[] start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return new Integer[] { 1 };
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Integer[] scope) {
        if(priorId != null) {
            insert new Document(Name='Test Me', FolderId=UserInfo.getUserId(), Body = Page.myPDFPage.getContentAsPDF());
        }
        priorId = insertEvents();
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        if(priorId != null) {
            Database.executeBatch(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I flip the problem around by generating the record *after* doing the callout in a batchable class, then keep chaining the batch. This seems awfully inefficient, but this does work in my developer edition org with the critical update enabled.

Comment: (Very) lateral thinking! Looks promising and I'll give it a go - thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on sfdcfox's idea and code, I've just tried this and it works:

```
public class FireEventsBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Integer>,
        Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

    // Entry point
    public static void execute(String requestId) {
        if (requestId != null) {
            Database.executeBatch(new FireEventsBatchable(requestId), 1);
        }
    }

    private String requestId;

    private FireEventsBatchable(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public Integer[] start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // With batch size of 1 execute gets called up to 8 times
        return new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Integer[] scope) {
        if (requestId != null) {
            if (Events.fireFor(requestId)) {
                requestId = Events.insertEvents();
            }
        } else {
            System.abortJob(bc.getJobId());
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // If more to do - chain to another job
        execute(requestId);
    }
}
```

The only tweak is to make a single `Batchable` handle the common case (in my case about 5 iterations) and to only chain in the rare cases (of more than 8 iterations). I've included a `System.abortJob` to stop early when the work is finished.

Seems very much a convoluted work-around for something that ought to be easier...