# ApexPages.getContent() Callout Error from Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, callout

I am receiving the following error when I run the below apex invocable method in my flow:

```
An Apex error occurred: System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

I believe what is happening here is that As of Winter '16, the PageReference getContent() method is treated as a callout.

I am struggling to understand how I can perform this action in a future context. My idea is to set the entire invocable method in a future context, but I am not sure if that is the best solution here.

```
/**
 * @description       : 
 * @author            : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
 * @group             : 
 * @last modified on  : 05-18-2022
 * @last modified by  : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
**/
global class SendAdvancedEmail {





    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Advanced Email')
    global static List <Results> SendAdvancedEmail(List<Requests> requests) {



        List<Results> results = new List<Results>();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> singleEmailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for (Requests curRequest : requests) 
        {
            Set<Id> contentDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> reportIds = new Set<Id>();
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
                if (curRequest.reports != null)
                 {
                    for (Report report : curRequest.reports) 
                    {
                        reportIds.add(report.Id);
                    }
                    // Add reports as attchments
                    attachments.addAll(addReportsAsEmailAttachment(reportIds));

                }

            // Create a new single email message object
            // that will send out a single email to the addresses in the To, CC & BCC list.
            
            // Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
            mail.setToAddresses(curRequest.toAddresses);
            mail.setCcAddresses(curRequest.ccAddresses);
            mail.setBccAddresses(curRequest.bccAddresses);     
            mail.setSenderDisplayName(curRequest.senderDisplayName); 
            mail.setReplyTo(curRequest.replyEmailAddress);      
            mail.setSubject(curRequest.subject);
            mail.setReplyTo(curRequest.replyEmailAddress);
            mail.setHtmlBody(curRequest.HTMLbody);
            mail.setPlainTextBody(curRequest.plainTextBody);


            singleEmailList.add(mail);


            

        }

        if (singleEmailList != null && singleEmailList.size() > 0)
        {
            Results result = new Results();
            List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> emailResults = new List<Messaging.SendEmailResult>();
            emailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(singleEmailList, false);


            for(Messaging.SendEmailResult emailResult : emailResults)
            {


                if(!emailResult.IsSuccess()) 
                {                 
                    result.isSuccess = false;   
                    List<Messaging.SendEmailError> errors = emailResult.getErrors();

                    if (errors.size() > 0){
                        result.errors = errors[0].getMessage();
                        result.statusCode = String.valueOf(errors[0].getStatusCode());
                        result.fields = errors[0].getFields();
                        
                    }                   
                } else{
                    result.isSuccess = true;
                }
            }
        }

        



        return results;
    }


    global static List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> addReportsAsEmailAttachment(Set<Id> reportIDs)
    {
        List<Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName,Name FROM Report where Id in :reportIDs];

        String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');
                
        //Get Report Name
        string reportName=(String)reportList.get(0).get('Name');
        
        //get instance Url
        String instanceName = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
        
        string url=instanceName+'/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&reportId='+reportId;
        
        ApexPages.PageReference objPage = new ApexPages.PageReference(url);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment objMsgEmailAttach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        objMsgEmailAttach.setFileName(reportName+'.csv');
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
            objMsgEmailAttach.setBody(blob.valueOf('Unit.Test'));
        }else{
            objMsgEmailAttach.setBody(objPage.getContent());
        }
        objMsgEmailAttach.setContentType('text/csv');

        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments=new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
        attachments.add(objMsgEmailAttach);


        return attachments;
    }


    global class Requests {
        @invocableVariable(label='To Addresses' required=true)
        global String[] toAddresses;

        @invocableVariable(label='CC Addresses' )
        global String[] ccAddresses;

        @invocableVariable(label='BCC Addresses' )
        global String[] bccAddresses; 


        @invocableVariable(label='Subject' required=true)
        global String subject;        

        @invocableVariable(label='Email HTML Body')
        global String HTMLbody;

        @invocableVariable(label='Email Plain Text Body')
        global String plainTextBody;

        @invocableVariable(label='Sender Display Name' )
        public String senderDisplayName;

        @invocableVariable(label='Sender Email Address' required=true)
        public String senderEmailAddress;

        @invocableVariable(label='Reply Email Address')
        public String replyEmailAddress;

        @invocableVariable(label='List of Content Documents (NOT CURRENTLY IN USE)')
        global List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocuments;
  
        @invocableVariable(label='List of Reports')
        global List<Report> reports;



    }

    global class Results {

        @InvocableVariable(label='Succesfully Sent')
        global boolean isSuccess;
        
        @invocableVariable(label='Error Messages')
        public String errors;

        @invocableVariable(label='Status Code')
        public String statusCode;

        @invocableVariable(label='Error Fields')
        public List<String> fields;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100167/how-to-mix-getcontentaspdf-calls-with-dml?

Comment: If your flow (or anything that called the flow) has done DML, then you are right, the getContent() is considered a callout and can't follow the DML in the same transaction. See if you can use [Async Flows](https://unofficialsf.com/winter-22-flow-sneak-preview/) (introduced Winter 22)?